# How to disable the start page in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have accidentally set a page as start page when debugging. Is there any solution to disable this function?

Comment: _something_ has to be the "startup" page/app - just set a different page to start page or different app to the startup project.

Comment: You do not mean the 'start page' of visual studio after starting without a solution, do you?

Comment: Have you had a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159187/debugging-web-apps-in-visual-studio-2010-is-annoying

Answer (score 26):

Yes, go to TOOLS->OPTIONS->ENVIRONMENT->STARTUP and there you have several options about what to do when starting VS

Comment: The question is not about Visual Studio Startup.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 has only the one option in the dropdown list

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2017 Pro: Right-click your Project (directly below the Solution entry) in the Solution Explorer. Select Properties. Click the Web tab. Select the appropriate Start Action.

Answer (score 1):

In solution explorer, right click on folder's path of your website (eg. D:...\My_website)and select property pages>start options> here you can set the specific page to start from

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little older but this pops up pretty high for removing the start page from the project on google so I'm going to answer it here now.

1. Click on your application in the solution manager
2. View -> Property Pages
3. Select the 'Web' tab on the left
4. Find 'Start Action' as a radio button with open input field.

What I would do is set the input field to be empty.  That way when you click to debug (if you're on a web app), it will just default to localhost.  Which I presume is what you want.